# Labelling points on a NumberLinePlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a list of points plotted using the command:

```
NumberLinePlot[{1, 1.5, 2}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red, PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Darker[Green], 
    PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Blue, PointSize[Large]}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

The output is of the form:

[image]

How can I label each point in the graph. Say, for instance, the red term is the first term in a sequence, the green term is the second term in the sequence etc. How can I label the plot such that this labelling, as $x_1, x_2$ is reflected in the graph. It'd be great if someone could suggest a way where I can introduce these labels directly on the graph, and not in the legend, so I don't necessarily have to color the points differently.

Answer (score 7):

Post-process to add labels:

```
labels={"label1","label2","label3"};
i=1;
NumberLinePlot[{1,1.5, 2}, PlotStyle-> {{Thick, Red, PointSize[Large]},
  {Thick, Darker[Green], PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Blue, PointSize[Large]}}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20] /. Point[x_]->{Point[x], Text[labels[[i++]], {0,1} + x]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Stealing @Mr.Wizard's idea of using `Tooltip`s with an alternative way to post-process

```
nlp = NumberLinePlot[Tooltip@@@Transpose[{{1,1.5, 2}, labels}], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red, PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Darker[Green], 
    PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Blue, PointSize[Large]}}];

Show[nlp /. Tooltip[x_, y_] :> {x, Text[y, {0,1} + x[[1,1]]]}, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update 2:** Neither of the methods above work in version 11.3. The following modification of the first method works:

```
labels = {"label1", "label2", "label3"};
i = 1;
NumberLinePlot[List /@ {1, 1.5, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> ({{Thick, Red, PointSize[Large]},
       {Thick, Darker[Green], PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Blue, 
      PointSize[Large]}}), 
   ImagePadding -> 20, Spacings -> {1/4, 0, 0}] /. 
 Point[x_] :> {Point[x], Text[labels[[i++]], {0, 1/4} + x]}
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to note the [example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) in the ListPlot documentation, but you got there first.

Answer (score 5):

[`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) gives you hover-over labels:

```
dat = {Tooltip[1, "x1"], Tooltip[1.5, "x2"], Tooltip[2, "x3"]};

p1 = NumberLinePlot[dat, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red, PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Darker[Green], 
    PointSize[Large]}, {Thick, Blue, PointSize[Large]}}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

I am working on always-visible labels now.

---

I could not quickly trace the handling of `Labeled` in `NumberLinePlot` but it seems it is not supported.  We could extract points and re-plot them with a function that does support `Labeled`, [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html):

```
pts = Cases[p1, Tooltip[{_[pt_]}, lbl_] :> Labeled[pt, lbl], -3];

Show[p1, ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> None], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh. But if I want to embed the graph in a PDF? For that, ideally, I was hoping there's a way I could label the points on the numberline and make that labelling apparent.

Comment: @JunaidAftab Yes, I understand.  Please see my updated answer.  This uses the automatically positioned labeling of `ListPlot` in an overlay of the `NumberLinePlot`.