# numberlineplot with labeled

Tags: plotting

I figure the answer to this may be really simple. Why does

```
ListPlot[MapThread[Labeled[ #1,#2,Left] &,{{1,5,-4,2}, {"pt1", "pt2", "pt3", "pt4"}}]]
```

plot and label the points, but

```
NumberLinePlot[MapThread[Labeled[ #1,#2,Left] &,{{1,5,-4,2}, {"pt1", "pt2", "pt3", "pt4"}}]]
```

doesn't label the points but still plots? If NumberLinePlot is incompatible with Labeled, is there a way around this to still properly put labels on the graphics output?

Comment: That is incorrect syntax for `NumberLinePlot`.  The documentation does not say that `NumberLinePlot` can take data in wrappers.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Labeling points in NumberLinePlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139520/125)